# Symmetries in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, eigenvalue, observables

I have the following question; if we an operator corresponding to a spacetime translation:
$$ \hat{\Omega}$$
and a hermitian operator, $$\hat{A}$$ commutes with this translation: $$[\hat{\Omega},\hat{A}]=0$$ do we consider the translation a symmetry or do we consider the the eigenvalues of $$\hat{A}$$ a symmetry?

Comment: Numbers are not symmetries. Translations might be depending on the theory.

Comment: I don't know what it means to "Consider the eigenvalues of $A$ a symmetry".

Answer (score 2):

A physical transformation of the state (such as a translation) is represented by a unitary operator $U$.

If $U$ commutes with the Hamiltonian for a given system, then we say that the physical transformation associated with $U$ is a symmetry of the system.

So, if you have some system described by a Hamiltonian $H_1$, and the the translation operator commutes with $H_1$, then we say translations are a symmetry of the system.

It's also possible that some other system, described by a different Hamiltonian $H_2$, will not commute with the translation operator. Then, translations are not a symmetry of that system.

Comment: I understand this, however more generally we can define a symmetry group as the group of all transformations under which the object is invariant. If our operator A is invariant under the translation. In this case do we say that this translation is a symmetry of the operator A?

Comment: @Adrien I have never heard of anyone saying "$U$ commutes with $A$ implies $U$ is a symmetry of $A$" unless $A$ is the Hamiltonian. In more advanced treatments of quantum mechanics, you can talk about an algebra of observables (commutation relations between members of a set of observables); then if two observables in that set commute you can find a basis where both are simultaneously diagonalized. But you would say both observables are part of a larger symmetry group, you wouldn't say one is a symmetry of the other.

Comment: @Adrien Thinking more, I wonder if I can rephrase your question as "If an operator $U$ is a symmetry of a system, then what is left invariant when acting with $U$?" If so, then the answer are amplitudes, and the invariance only needs to work up to a phase. In other words, given two arbitrary states $\Psi$ and $\Phi$, then after acting with a symmetry $U$ the inner product should be the same: $(U \Psi, U \Phi) = e^{i \lambda} (\Psi, \Phi)$, where $(a, b)$ is the inner product of the states $a$ and $b$ and where $\lambda$ is some real number. Any operator satisfying this property is a symmetry.

Comment: For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem

Comment: Sorry for the slow response fell down a bit of a rabbit hole when it comes to symmetries; i was getting confused because i thought you could treat individual operators as objects, under which you can perform a symmetry operation. The wigner theorem is useful though thanks!